# Filtering out row in Pyspark when there is a word from other table in any column

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am new to pyspark and I want to write a query something like,

`select * from table1 where column like '%word1%'` which we write in sql or hive.

I am writing the following command,

```
data = sqlCtx.sql('select * from table1 where column like '%word1%')
```

But I am getting errors such as,

```
NameError: name 'word1' is not defined
```

I am ideally thinking of having a condition like,

```
select word_name from table2;
```

would give a list of words and whenever those words occur in table1 in any column, I want to filter out those entries and give out the remaining rows and place it in a dataframe.

Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `"select * from table1 where column like '%word1%'")`?

Comment: @Dair Oh yes.. My bad ! But can you help me in second requirement where we can fetch words from table2 and filter it out?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about the SQL module in spark too well. Just seemed like it might of been a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, "like" function works in pyspark just fine and just like in SQL. With DataFrame API and with SQL API.
Examples:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
duncan_prestige = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Duncan", "car")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(duncan_prestige.data.reset_index())

    index   type    income  education   prestige
0   accountant  prof    62  86  82
1   pilot   prof    72  76  83
2   architect   prof    75  92  90
3   author  prof    55  90  76
```

DataFrame API:

```
df.filter(df['index'].like('%ilo%')).toPandas()

    index   type    income  education   prestige
0   pilot   prof    72  76  83
```

Or with SQL

```
df.registerTempTable('df')
sqlContext.sql("select * from df d where d.index like '%ilo%' ").toPandas()
```

And with join (silly but to prove the point)

```
qry = """
select d1.* 
from df d1 join df d2 
    on ( d1.index  = d2.index)
where d1.index like '%ilo%' and d2.index like concat('%', d1.index , '%')
"""
sqlContext.sql(qry).toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something might be simpler:

```
input_list = tbl1.select('col1').distinct().rdd.map(lambda x: x).collect()
tbl2.where(col('col2').isin(input_list) == False)
```